# How to use my own identity information for git commit

Tags: git, github, git-fork

Today I try to sync fork repository (https://github.com/donhuvy/spring-boot/) from source repository (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot).

```
cd /d Desktop
git clone https://github.com/donhuvy/spring-boot.git
cd spring-boot
git remote add upstream https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot.git
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
git push
```

Then I enter my username, password in a Windows pop-up diaglog, wait a moment, Git inform success. This is my specific commit: https://github.com/donhuvy/spring-boot/commit/e62da83292c69aa97bbe9135ff337a11f8b87bb8

I use `git` command from Windows Operating System (`Git 2.8.3.windows.1`).

`cmd` ask me username and password, I enter it before push source code to my own fork repository. But my account don't appear as committer, It appear computer's name (`DCV`), it isn't my name/my Github account (`donhuvy`). How I do what I want (I prefer using command line than GitHub desktop for Windows GUI)?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When on windows you can do one of two ways:

Install [GitHub desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) and log into your github account

or

```
git config --global user.name "<your github username>"
git config --global user.email <github email>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try at next commit time. Then I will vote up/accept the answer.